# How to group a data by week and show a 0 when there is no data

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a set of numbers attached to dates. What I need to do is take those numbers and group them by calendar week. Generally speaking, that works fine...except for when there's a week when there are no numbers.

Here's the hash of numbers:

```
chart_numbers = {"2014-02-20"=>1, "2014-02-23"=>4, "2014-02-24"=>1, "2014-03-06"=>1, "2014-03-14"=>3, "2014-03-15"=>1, "2014-03-17"=>1, "2014-03-20"=>1, "2014-03-21"=>1, "2014-03-24"=>1, "2014-03-25"=>1, "2014-03-28"=>1, "2014-04-05"=>1, "2014-04-07"=>1}
```

Here are the "week" timestamps (these are use for the javascript charting library). As you can see, there are 9 timestamps.

```
chart_weekly_timestamps = [1392595199, 1393199999, 1393804799, 1394409599, 1395014399, 1395619199, 1396223999, 1396828799, 1397433599]
```

Finally, here's the code that takes the `chart_numbers` and sums them up in to calendar weeks.

```
chart_week = Hash[ chart_numbers.map { |h, v| [h, v] } ].group_by { |h, v| Date.parse(h).cweek }.values.map{ |v| v.sum { |vv| vv.last } }.map{ |v| v.round(0) }  %>
```

The output from that is: `[5, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1]`

And there's where the problem lies. There are only 8 items in that array. But I need to match it up to the week timestamps above, which have 9 array items.

So what I need to do is when there's a week with no data, I need to show a `0` as an array item.

Comment: Are you using Ruby on Rails and retrieving the data from a database? Also, are you aware that `Hash[ chart_numbers.map { |h, v| [h, v] } ]` is a waste, since all it does it give you back the original hash?

Comment: @Cupcake: Yes...though the hash that I'm pulling this data from is used by a few other things, so modifying the query isn't really all that convenient.

Comment: What does `chart_weekly_timestamps` have to do with `chart_numbers`?

Comment: I suggest setting up a counting hash, with keys equal to the weeks in the range and values the numbers of matches, initialized to zero. Then just each through chart_numbers, doing += 1 on the applicable value of the hash, then hash.values at the end to return your desired array. This requires v.1.9+ to keep the hash elements ordered. For earlier versions, `hash.sort.map(&:last)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: That sounds like a potential answer. An example of how to do that in an answer would be great. And I'm using Ruby 2.0.

Comment: I posted an answer a couple of minutes after you left your comment, but must confess I was already working it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to construct the array you want.

**Code**

```
require 'date'

a = chart_numbers.map { |d,n| [Date.parse(d).cweek, n] }
h = (a.min_by(&:first).first..(a.max_by(&:first).first)).each_with_object({}) \
      { |(w,_),h| h[w] = 0 }
a.each { |w,n| h[w] += n }    
h.values
```

For Ruby versions prior to 1.9, add `.sort` to the end of the last line.

**Explanation**

I modified the last date in `chart_numbers` to produce an unrepresented week
and also moved the date at offset 7 to offset 1 so they would not be ordered.

```
chart_numbers =
  {"2014-02-20"=>1, "2014-03-20"=>1, "2014-02-23"=>4, "2014-02-24"=>1,
   "2014-03-06"=>1, "2014-03-14"=>3, "2014-03-15"=>1, "2014-03-17"=>1, 
   "2014-03-21"=>1, "2014-03-24"=>1, "2014-03-25"=>1, "2014-03-28"=>1,
   "2014-04-05"=>1, "2014-04-17"=>1}
```

Convert the dates to weeks and `chart_numbers` to an array.

```
a = chart_numbers.map { |d,n| [Date.parse(d).cweek, n] }
  #=> [[8 , 1], [12, 1], [8 , 4], [9 , 1], [10, 1], [11, 3], [11, 1],
  #    [12, 1], [12, 1], [13, 1], [13, 1], [13, 1], [14, 1], [16, 1]]
```

Note there is no week 15. Now create a hash with keys from 8 through 16, with all values zero.

```
h = (a.min_by(&:first).first..(a.max_by(&:first).first)).each_with_object({}) \
      { |(w,_),h| h[w] = 0 }
  #=> {8=>0, 9=>0, 10=>0, 11=>0, 12=>0, 13=>0, 14=>0, 15=>0, 16=>0}
```

Add up the values from the original hash:

```
a.each { |w,n| h[w] += n }
```

so now

```
h #=> {8=>5, 9=>1, 10=>1, 11=>4, 12=>3, 13=>3, 14=>1, 15=>0, 16=>1}
```

Retrieve the hash values:

```
h.values
  #=> [5, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently published a gem [OrderedWeek](https://github.com/thermaldonkey/ordered_week) that handles groups of days as a single unit. Take a gander. I'd love some feedback on it as well.